# How do I pass a function as a parameter to run multiple times?

Tags: javascript, function, parameters

I don't understand function closures and anonymous functions very well. What I'm trying to do is create a function that runs the inputted function randomly based on a dice roll:

```
repeat(1,6,foobar());

function repeat(numDie, dieType, func){
    var total = 0;
    for (var i=0; i < numDie; i++){
        var dieRoll = Math.floor(Math.random()*dieType)+1;
        total += dieRoll;
    }
    for (var x=0; x < total; x++){
        func();
    }
}
```

What exactly am I doing wrong here? Do I have to store the function in a variable to use it?

Comment: No, close voter, this question is more than likely to help future visitors.

Comment: http://helephant.com/2008/08/19/functions-are-first-class-objects-in-javascript/

Comment: @Bolt: Except that there are probably hundreds of duplicates; this seems to come up every day.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By writing `foobar()`, you're *calling* `foobar` and passing its return value.

Remove the parentheses to pass the function instead of calling it.

Comment: ... and what if foobar() takes parameters?

Comment: @rob: Then you need to pass an anonymous function.

Answer (score 6):

Change:

repeat(1,6,foobar());

to

```
repeat(1,6,foobar);
```